# Is $f^{-1}(1)$ a submanifold of $\Bbb S^2\times \Bbb S^2$?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

We consider $f:\Bbb S^2\times\Bbb S^2\to\Bbb R$ as the standard dot product of two points in $\Bbb R^3$. We need to prove that $f^{-1}(1)$ is a regular submanifold of $\Bbb S^2\times\Bbb S^2$.

If $1$ were a regular value, then it would be direct, but it isn't (the jacobian of $f$ is zero in every two points $x$ and $y$ such that $x=y$, and $f(x,x)=1$). Also, the rank of $f$ is not constant (since it can vary from $1$ and $2$).

I don't understand well how to prove it by definition. Could anyone please help me out?

Comment: Can you describe the set $f^{-1}(1)$ in words and see that it is a manifold in another way?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure about your statement that it isn't a regular value. How can the rank be $2$ when the differential has a $1$ dimensional codomain?

Comment: Oh wait, I confused the exercise with a different one. In this case, the jacobian matrix of $f$ is $6 \times 1$, not $3\times 2$. Then $1$ is a regular value! My bad!

Comment: NO! $1$ is not a regular value..... I suggest you to forget about the regular value stuff and try to write down $f^{-1}(1)$ explicitly. Hint: $x \cdot y \le |x| |y|$

Comment: And the jacobian is *not* $1\times 6$.

Comment: I know that $f^{-1}(1)$ consists of all of the pair of points $(x,y)$ such that $x=y$, since the norm of any point of the unit sphere is 1, and no other two points in the sphere verify $\langle x,y\rangle=1$. Is this alright?

Comment: Yes. So you need to show $\{ (x, x) \in S^2 \times S^2 : x\in S^2\}$ is a regular submanifold.

Comment: Sorry for beating around the bush, but couldn't we consider $g(x,x)=\|x\|_2^2$ and say that $A = \{(x,x)\in\Bbb S^2\times\Bbb S^2:x\in\Bbb S^2\} = g^{-1}(1)$? Why isn't $1$ a regular value in here?

Comment: If it is a regular value, the level set would be a $4-1=3$ dimensional submanifold, which obviously isn't the case here.

Comment: Wouldn't it be $6-1=5$, since $\Bbb S^2\times\Bbb S^2\subset\Bbb R^6$?

Comment: Here's a more easily-visualized problem with the same issue: "Define $f:\mathbf{R}^{2} \to \mathbf{R}$ by $f(x, y) = (x - y)^2$. Show that $f^{-1}(0)$ is a regular submanifold." Can you see how we might proceed?

Comment: As the set in the question, $f^{-1}(0)=\{(x,x)\in\Bbb R^2 : x\in\Bbb R\}$. We could do it through adapted charts, or by checking if the rank of $f$ is constant, perhaps?

Comment: The rank of $f$ is not constant. Just forget about $f$.....

Comment: Since $\mathbb S^2 \times \mathbb S^2$ is 4-dimensional, the dimension formula would be $4-1=3$. The fact that  $\mathbb S^2 \times \mathbb S^2$ is embedded in $\mathbb R^6$ is irrelevant for purposes of understanding level sets **in the submanifold $\mathbb S^2 \times \mathbb S^2$**.

Answer (score 2):

The following result can be found in Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, Proposition 5.7.

> Let $M, N$ be smooth manifold and let $g : M\to N$ be a smooth map. Then the graph of $g$
> $$ \Gamma_g =\{ (x, g(x)) \in M \times N : x\in M\}$$
> is an embedded submanifold of dimension $m = \dim (M)$.

Setting $M = N = \mathbb S^2$ and $g : \mathbb S^2 \to \mathbb S^2$, $g(x) = x$, then

$$D =  \{ (x, x) \in \mathbb S^2 \times \mathbb S^2 : x\in \mathbb S^2\}$$
is an embedded submanifold of $\mathbb S^2 \times \mathbb S^2$. Since $f^{-1}(1) = D$, $f^{-1}(1)$ is an embedded submanifold of $\mathbb S^2 \times \mathbb S^2$.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know this result, at least I didn't have it in my notes. The answer ends up being quite short, but I don't think I can use it. Thanks for bringing this result up, though! If there isn't any other answer, I'll give you the bounty!

Comment: What is your definition of regular submanifold? @GreekCorpse

Comment: A smooth manifold $P$ contained in a smooth manifold $M$ such that the inclusion is a one-to-one inmersion and $P$ has the induced topology of $M$.